# Window drag delay to move across spaces: Adjust in Yosemite

Tags: macos, spaces

The tip presented [here (http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/10/change-the-delay-when-dragging-windows-within-spaces/)](http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/10/change-the-delay-when-dragging-windows-within-spaces/) no longer works.

Is there a new setting we can use?

I know how petty this sounds, but 1000 milliseconds is far too long to wait.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you have hotkeys set up for Space changing [I use ctr/numpad] then you can grab the title bar & hit the hotkey for instant transition to any Space.

Comment: Yep, I already do this, but I don't really want to use up "valuable" key combo slots for this, plus it's extremely awkward to do any keyboard stuff while actively dragging a window with the trackpad.

Comment: ah, trackpad… work of the devil ;) also, no numpad, so fewer key combo options. Understand.

Comment: Yup I can use all the space I can get...

Comment: Agree; there's no such thing as too much desktop space - I have 2x27" 2k screens & still use 6 Spaces ;)